# Can I have different MIME type mappings for different files with the same extension (in the same folder)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, middleware, mime-types

**Introduction**

I'm configuring MIMEs for static files as usual, something like this (and that works fine, keep reading so you get to the actual question):

```
var defaultStaticFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "content"));
var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();            
var defaultStaticFilesRequestPath = "/content";
// This serves static files from the 'content' directory.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = defaultStaticFileProvider,
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = false,
    RequestPath = defaultStaticFilesRequestPath,
    ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
});
```

The previous code is mapping the **.json** extension to **application/json** by default. Works fine.

**Question**

What I want is to change that mapping to **application/manifest+json** but only for one file: manifest.json

So, I tried to add another configuration like this (not working):

```
// Add custom options for manifest.json only.
var manifestContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
manifestContentTypeProvider.Mappings.Clear();
manifestContentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".json", "application/manifest+json");
var manifestStaticFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "content/en/app"));
var manifestStaticFileRequestPath = "/content/en/app/manifest.json";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = manifestStaticFileProvider,
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = false,
    RequestPath = manifestStaticFileRequestPath,
    ContentTypeProvider = manifestContentTypeProvider
});
```

Just to clarify, I have added the above code right after the previous one.

Hope the question is clear enough, I'll be checking for comments proposing editing tips to make it better anyways.

Comment: A mime file each attachment is started with a new line with two dashes.  See msdn sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StaticFileOptions` class has an [`OnPrepareResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse) property to which you can assign an `Action` in order to change the HTTP response headers.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse)

> Called after the status code and headers have been set, but before the body has been written. This can be used to add or change the response headers.

In that `Action` you check for the `manifest.json` file and set/change the `content-type` header accordingly. That action has an [`StaticFileResponseContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.staticfileresponsecontext)  input argument  with access to the `HttpContext` and `File`.

```
var options = new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = staticFileResponseContext =>
    {
        var httpContext = staticFileResponseContext.Context;

        // Request path check:
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.Equals("/content/en/app/manifest.json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        // or file name only check via: 
        // if (staticFileResponseContext.File.Name.Equals("manifest.json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/manifest+json"
        }
    },
    // Your other custom configuration
    FileProvider = defaultStaticFileProvider,
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = false,
    RequestPath = defaultStaticFilesRequestPath
};

app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

Comment: this looks pretty good, I think I'll be accepting your answer soon today, thanks